# I can't resize Mat-calendar , remain always big

Tags: angular, typescript

I create one MatDialog, with inline Mat-Calendar, but I can't resize the calendar, the Dialog  I'm able to resize by putting the width and heigth, but tha table of days remain like this picture, so big!.

```
<mat-card class="">
  <div class="flex justify-around items-center">
    <button mat-button (click)="today()">Today</button>
    <button mat-flat-button (click)="clearSelected()"[color]="'accent'">Clear</button>
    <button mat-flat-button (click)="select($event)" [color]="'primary'">Select</button>
  </div>
  <mat-calendar
    [dateClass]="dateClass()"
    #picker panelClass="endDate"
    [(selected)]="selectedDate"
    (selectedChange)="onSelect($event)">
  </mat-calendar>
```

```
.example-header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
::ng-deep.md-datepicker-input-container {
    width: 200px;
}
```

for open the dialog I use this code:

```
this._matDialog.open(DialogDueDateTableDialog, {
                // width: '300px',
                // height: 'h-full',
                // autoFocus: false,
                // maxHeight: '90vh', //you can adjust the value as per your view
                data: {
                    content:this.activatedRow,
                    column: column.name,
                    row:    row,
                    allData: this.rowData
                }
            })
            .afterClosed()
            .pipe(
                tap(() => this.activatedRow = null)
            );
```

[image]

if I try to enable the width (width: '300px') the final resul is the second image[image]
Ho can resize correctly?
like the image 3?[image]

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz with your code and styles?

Comment: too complicate (time..I don't have time) create on stackblitz, I use also luxon library